# Excel sheet parsing

Tags: parseexcel

I'm trying to parse one Excel spreadsheet which has a field named "Status" (possible values PASS/FAIL).
I want the total no. of records for PASS status and that of FAIL status.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: specifying which language may help..

Answer (score 0):

Try apache POI http://poi.apache.org

Comment: cant't we write a simple macro for this?

Comment: You mean a formula in a cell?

Comment: so I'm sorry but a can't help you further